# How to write class parameters into hiera

Tags: puppet, hiera

I'm just getting into hiera and have now configured it, my attempts at migrating to hiera have been frustratingly hard as I'm not able to get the write syntax. Can someone help me in converting the below from a class declaration to hiera?

Current declarations in my declare.pp file:

```
class profile::web {
  class { 'nsswitch':
    automount => 'files',
    hosts => ['files','dns'],
  }
}

class { 'sudo': }
    sudo::conf { 'web-users':
    sudo_config_dir => '/etc/sudoers.d/',
    source => 'puppet:///files/web/web-users.conf',
}
```

Thanks
Dan

Comment: Hiera is not meant for declaring classes. In hiera you store data that you can use within your puppet manifests. You declare a class within puppet and can use hiera to supply it the data based on facts like the node name, environment, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
---
nsswitch::automount:  files
nsswitch::hosts:
  - files
  - dns
```

In hiera files; never use tabs!!

In your manifest you can use

```
include nsswitch
```

OR you can load a list of classes from Hiera with the hiera_include function:

```
hiera_include('classes')
```

You'll need an array of classes in your Hiera file then.

Comment: For creating resources (sudo::conf!) you'll need the create_resources function.

Comment: Why never use tabs in hiera files? Is that specific to YAML or also to JSON (and other) data formats as well?

Comment: It's a yaml-thing. The parser will cough up mysterious error messages that have nothing to do with 'get that damn tab out of your yaml-file!'